# Rasterize overlapping sf objects in R and specify which values to use for pixels

Tags: r, gis, spatial-interpolation, rasterize

I have an sf dataframe with multiple polygons in R (each row is a square in a slightly different location with a different value associated with it). There are also some gaps between the polygons. I would like to rasterize the sf dataframe using stars::st_rasterize (using a second sf dataframe as the extent of the new raster) but am running into 2 issues.

1. When there are multiple overlapping sf objects in a raster pixel, I would like to specify that I want the raster pixel to take the lowest possible value from the sf objects.
2. In the rasterizing process, I would like to fill in the gaps between the sf objects using interpolation based on the values of the nearest sf objects. In other words, I don't want the raster to have NA values within the extent of the second sf df.

Here are some dummy sf dataframes:

a) the polygon that will be the extent of the raster

```
### load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(stars)

### set vertices
polygon_vertices <- matrix(c(-1489008, 1369848,
                             -1488191, 1370128,
                             -1488132, 1369347,
                             -1488985, 1369243,
                             -1489008, 1369848),
                           ncol = 2,
                           byrow = TRUE) 

### make it a polygon
polygon_extent <- st_polygon(list(polygon_vertices))

### make it an sf object and set the crs
polygon_extent <- polygon_extent %>%
  st_sfc(crs = 6350)
```

b) the sf dataframe with the overlapping sf objects

```
### set the vertices for the rows of the sf df
p1_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488355, 1369737,  
                        -1488355, 1370072,  
                        -1488237, 1370112, 
                        -1488190, 1370112,
                        -1488162, 1369737,
                        -1488355, 1369737),
                      ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
p2_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488355, 1369737,  
                        -1488355, 1370072,  
                        -1488237, 1370112, 
                        -1488190, 1370112,
                        -1488162, 1369737,
                        -1488355, 1369737),
                      ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
p3_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488253, 1369484,  
                        -1488253, 1369859,  
                        -1488171, 1369859, 
                        -1488143, 1369484,
                        -1488253, 1369484),
                      ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) 
p4_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488292, 1369795,  
                        -1488292, 1370093,  
                        -1488191, 1370128, 
                        -1488166, 1369795,
                        -1488292, 1369795),
                      ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) 
p5_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488260, 1369634,  
                        -1488154, 1369634,  
                        -1488132, 1369347, 
                        -1488260, 1369332,
                        -1488260, 1369634),
                      ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) 
p6_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488255, 1369734,  
                        -1488630, 1369734,  
                        -1488630, 1369977, 
                        -1488255, 1370106,
                        -1488255, 1369734),
                      ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) 
p7_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488240, 1369419,  
                        -1488615, 1369419,  
                        -1488615, 1369794, 
                        -1488240, 1369794,
                        -1488240, 1369419),
                      ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) 
p8_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488212, 1370120,  
                        -1488191, 1370128,  
                        -1488190, 1370120, 
                        -1488212, 1370120),
                      ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
p9_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488970, 1369519,  
                        -1488995, 1369519,  
                        -1489008, 1369848, 
                        -1488970, 1369861,
                        -1488970, 1369519),
                      ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) 
p10_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488970, 1369519,  
                        -1488995, 1369519,  
                        -1489008, 1369848, 
                        -1488970, 1369861,
                        -1488970, 1369519),
                      ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) 
p11_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488518, 1369823,  
                         -1488518, 1370016,  
                         -1488191, 1370128, 
                         -1488168, 1369823,
                         -1488518, 1369823),
                       ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
p12_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488452, 1369986,  
                         -1488452, 1370039,  
                         -1488191, 1370128, 
                         -1488180, 1369986,
                         -1488452, 1369986),
                       ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
p13_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488705, 1369618,  
                         -1488999, 1369618,  
                         -1489008, 1369848, 
                         -1488705, 1369952,
                         -1488705, 1369618),
                       ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) 
p14_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488804, 1369607,  
                         -1488999, 1369607,  
                         -1489008, 1369848, 
                         -1488804, 1369918,
                         -1488804, 1369607),
                       ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
p15_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488921, 1369704,  
                         -1489002, 1369704,  
                         -1489008, 1369848, 
                         -1488921, 1369878,
                         -1488921, 1369704),
                       ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) 
p16_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488299, 1369901,  
                         -1488674, 1369901,  
                         -1488674, 1369962, 
                         -1488299, 1370091,
                         -1488299, 1369901),
                       ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)  
p17_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488904, 1369779,  
                         -1489005, 1369779,  
                         -1489008, 1369848, 
                         -1488904, 1369884,
                         -1488904, 1369779),
                       ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) 
p18_vertices <- matrix(c(-1488525, 1369926,  
                         -1488780, 1369926,  
                         -1488525, 1370013, 
                         -1488525, 1369926),
                       ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) 

### combine all of them into an sf df
sf_boxes <- st_sf(pix_value = c(1:18),  # Unique identifier for each polygon
  geometry = st_sfc(st_polygon(list(p1_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p2_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p3_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p4_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p5_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p6_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p7_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p8_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p9_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p10_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p11_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p12_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p13_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p14_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p15_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p16_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p17_vertices)),
                    st_polygon(list(p18_vertices))),
  crs = 6350)
```

So here's what that looks like:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = polygon_extent, color = "gray") +
  geom_sf(data = sf_boxes, aes(color = as.character(pix_value),
                                  fill = as.character(pix_value)),
          alpha = 0.2) +
  NULL
```

[image: here's what that looks like]

And then I can rasterize it, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to set the code so that 1) each raster pixel with overlapping sf objects from sf_boxes gets the lowest value assigned to it and 2) the missing values within the extent of polygon_extent are filled in.

```
### rasterize
dummy_raster <- st_rasterize(sf_boxes,
                          st_as_stars(st_bbox(polygon_extent),
                                      nx = 399,
                                      ny = 460))
plot(dummy_raster)
```

[image: and here's what that looks like]
Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `terra::rasterize`

Your polygons

```
wkt <- c('POLYGON ((-1488355 1369737, -1488355 1370072, -1488237 1370112, -1488190 1370112, -1488162 1369737, -1488355 1369737))', 'POLYGON ((-1488355 1369737, -1488355 1370072, -1488237 1370112, -1488190 1370112, -1488162 1369737, -1488355 1369737))', 'POLYGON ((-1488253 1369484, -1488253 1369859, -1488171 1369859, -1488143 1369484, -1488253 1369484))', 'POLYGON ((-1488292 1369795, -1488292 1370093, -1488191 1370128, -1488166 1369795, -1488292 1369795))', 'POLYGON ((-1488260 1369634, -1488154 1369634, -1488132 1369347, -1488260 1369332, -1488260 1369634))', 'POLYGON ((-1488255 1369734, -1488630 1369734, -1488630 1369977, -1488255 1370106, -1488255 1369734))', 'POLYGON ((-1488240 1369419, -1488615 1369419, -1488615 1369794, -1488240 1369794, -1488240 1369419))', 'POLYGON ((-1488212 1370120, -1488191 1370128, -1488190 1370120, -1488212 1370120))', 'POLYGON ((-1488970 1369519, -1488995 1369519, -1489008 1369848, -1488970 1369861, -1488970 1369519))', 'POLYGON ((-1488970 1369519, -1488995 1369519, -1489008 1369848, -1488970 1369861, -1488970 1369519))', 'POLYGON ((-1488518 1369823, -1488518 1370016, -1488191 1370128, -1488168 1369823, -1488518 1369823))', 'POLYGON ((-1488452 1369986, -1488452 1370039, -1488191 1370128, -1488180 1369986, -1488452 1369986))', 'POLYGON ((-1488705 1369618, -1488999 1369618, -1489008 1369848, -1488705 1369952, -1488705 1369618))', 'POLYGON ((-1488804 1369607, -1488999 1369607, -1489008 1369848, -1488804 1369918, -1488804 1369607))', 'POLYGON ((-1488921 1369704, -1489002 1369704, -1489008 1369848, -1488921 1369878, -1488921 1369704))', 'POLYGON ((-1488299 1369901, -1488674 1369901, -1488674 1369962, -1488299 1370091, -1488299 1369901))', 'POLYGON ((-1488904 1369779, -1489005 1369779, -1489008 1369848, -1488904 1369884, -1488904 1369779))', 'POLYGON ((-1488525 1369926, -1488780 1369926, -1488525 1370013, -1488525 1369926))')

library(terra)
v <- vect(wkt)
values(v) <- data.frame(ID=1:nrow(v))
```

Solution, use `terra::rasterize` with arguments `fun` and `background`

```
r <- rast(v, res=2)
x <- rasterize(v, r, "ID", fun="min", background=0)
plot(x)
```

You could also achieve this more "manually" with

```
r <- rast(v, res=2)
v <- sort(v, "ID", TRUE)
x <- rasterize(v, r, "ID")
x <- subst(x, NA, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly for rasterizing the polygons and dealing with the overlaps! I really appreciate the help. Is there a quick way to fill in the zeroes in the raster (where there is no data) using nearest neighbor interpolation or something along those lines?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out! Thanks again for the help with the overlaps!